# Why isn't Drools working with Java 8?

Tags: maven, drools, java-8, surefire

I just installed the final version of Java 8.  When I try to build my project with Maven, many tests fail if I use Java 8, but pass fine with Java 7.  I've tried running it via the command line with JAVA_HOME set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0 and via Eclipse with jdk1.8.0 selected as the default JRE in Installed JREs.  Both fail.  Note that the tests that fail all use Drools 6 (and its dependencies).

Here is the output:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test set: com.local.lds.rules.LocmChiTest
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 3, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.245 sec <<< FAILURE!
test(com.local.lds.rules.LocmChiTest)  Time elapsed: 0.001 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:187)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at mockit.internal.util.MethodReflection.invoke(MethodReflection.java:63)
    at mockit.Invocation.proceed(Invocation.java:192)
    at mockit.integration.junit4.internal.BlockJUnit4ClassRunnerDecorator.createTest(BlockJUnit4ClassRunnerDecorator.java:59)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor7.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at mockit.internal.util.MethodReflection.invokeWithCheckedThrows(MethodReflection.java:95)
    at mockit.internal.mockups.MockMethodBridge.callMock(MockMethodBridge.java:75)
    at mockit.internal.mockups.MockMethodBridge.invoke(MockMethodBridge.java:41)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:233)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: wrong class format
    at org.drools.compiler.commons.jci.compilers.EclipseJavaCompiler$2.findType(EclipseJavaCompiler.java:279)
    at org.drools.compiler.commons.jci.compilers.EclipseJavaCompiler$2.findType(EclipseJavaCompiler.java:219)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.askForType(LookupEnvironment.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.UnresolvedReferenceBinding.resolve(UnresolvedReferenceBinding.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.resolveType(BinaryTypeBinding.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ParameterizedTypeBinding.resolve(ParameterizedTypeBinding.java:861)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.resolveType(BinaryTypeBinding.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.resolveTypeFor(BinaryTypeBinding.java:1081)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.getField(BinaryTypeBinding.java:869)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.findField(Scope.java:1052)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.findField(Scope.java:998)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.MethodScope.findField(MethodScope.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BlockScope.getBinding(BlockScope.java:474)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.QualifiedNameReference.resolveType(QualifiedNameReference.java:930)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.MessageSend.resolveType(MessageSend.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.Expression.resolve(Expression.java:947)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.Block.resolve(Block.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.IfStatement.resolve(IfStatement.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.AbstractMethodDeclaration.resolveStatements(AbstractMethodDeclaration.java:456)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.MethodDeclaration.resolveStatements(MethodDeclaration.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.AbstractMethodDeclaration.resolve(AbstractMethodDeclaration.java:415)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.resolve(TypeDeclaration.java:1148)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.resolve(TypeDeclaration.java:1258)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.CompilationUnitDeclaration.resolve(CompilationUnitDeclaration.java:539)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.process(Compiler.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:468)
    at org.drools.compiler.commons.jci.compilers.EclipseJavaCompiler.compile(EclipseJavaCompiler.java:405)
    at org.drools.compiler.commons.jci.compilers.AbstractJavaCompiler.compile(AbstractJavaCompiler.java:49)
    at org.drools.compiler.rule.builder.dialect.java.JavaDialect.compileAll(JavaDialect.java:405)
    at org.drools.compiler.compiler.DialectCompiletimeRegistry.compileAll(DialectCompiletimeRegistry.java:46)
    at org.drools.compiler.compiler.PackageRegistry.compileAll(PackageRegistry.java:110)
    at org.drools.compiler.compiler.PackageBuilder.compileAll(PackageBuilder.java:1334)
    at org.drools.compiler.compiler.PackageBuilder.compileAllRules(PackageBuilder.java:975)
    at org.drools.compiler.compiler.CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.buildRules(CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:266)
    at org.drools.compiler.compiler.CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.buildPackages(CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:98)
    at org.drools.compiler.compiler.CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.build(CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:87)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieModule.buildKnowledgePackages(AbstractKieModule.java:204)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieProject.verify(AbstractKieProject.java:39)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.buildKieProject(KieBuilderImpl.java:323)
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieBuilderImpl.buildAll(KieBuilderImpl.java:193)
    at com.local.lds.rules.RuleEngineManager.buildKieBase(RuleEngineManager.java:90)
    at com.local.lds.rules.LocmChiTest.<clinit>(LocmChiTest.java:33)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFormatException
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFileReader.<init>(ClassFileReader.java:372)
    at org.drools.compiler.commons.jci.compilers.EclipseJavaCompiler$2.createNameEnvironmentAnswer(EclipseJavaCompiler.java:303)
    at org.drools.compiler.commons.jci.compilers.EclipseJavaCompiler$2.findType(EclipseJavaCompiler.java:274)
    ... 82 more
testNoFeatured(com.local.lds.rules.LocmChiTest)  Time elapsed: 0 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.local.lds.rules.LocmChiTest
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:187)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at mockit.internal.util.MethodReflection.invoke(MethodReflection.java:63)
    at mockit.Invocation.proceed(Invocation.java:192)
    at mockit.integration.junit4.internal.BlockJUnit4ClassRunnerDecorator.createTest(BlockJUnit4ClassRunnerDecorator.java:59)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor7.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at mockit.internal.util.MethodReflection.invokeWithCheckedThrows(MethodReflection.java:95)
    at mockit.internal.mockups.MockMethodBridge.callMock(MockMethodBridge.java:75)
    at mockit.internal.mockups.MockMethodBridge.invoke(MockMethodBridge.java:41)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:233)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
testFeaturedSort(com.local.lds.rules.LocmChiTest)  Time elapsed: 0.001 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.local.lds.rules.LocmChiTest
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:187)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at mockit.internal.util.MethodReflection.invoke(MethodReflection.java:63)
    at mockit.Invocation.proceed(Invocation.java:192)
    at mockit.integration.junit4.internal.BlockJUnit4ClassRunnerDecorator.createTest(BlockJUnit4ClassRunnerDecorator.java:59)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor7.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at mockit.internal.util.MethodReflection.invokeWithCheckedThrows(MethodReflection.java:95)
    at mockit.internal.mockups.MockMethodBridge.callMock(MockMethodBridge.java:75)
    at mockit.internal.mockups.MockMethodBridge.invoke(MockMethodBridge.java:41)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:233)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
```

So is this a problem with Java 8, Maven, the Surefire plugin, or Drools?

Comment: Maybe this would help? https://www.java.net/forum/topic/jdk/java-se-snapshots-project-feedback/drools-stop-working-java-8

Comment: Where did you get the final of JDK 8? It's not available on the JDK8 download page yet (despite that it was targeted to release yesterday).

Comment: @Geoffreydesmet it is: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

Comment: Google finds this, too I had similar problem like you. I am using latest JDK8 b114 and similar error happened for me when I tried to compile stylesheet. I've created JIRA https://issues.jboss.org/browse/DROOLS-329 and I also added steps with workaround which helped me (Use JANINO compiler instead of default ECLIPSE compiler)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Looks like a bug in Drools (in the Eclipse compiler which is the default):

- [Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1078146)
- [JIRA](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/DROOLS-329) (thanks Laune)

They're looking into fixing it in `6.1.0.Beta2`.

Meanwhile, try this **workaround**:
Override the `ecj` dependency to version `4.3.1`.

Comment: If I'm not using Maven, how should I override ecj dependency? I couldn't find which of the drools jars has eclipse compiler.

Comment: It's the jar called `ecj-*.jar`.

The issue is fixed on master btw, so it will be part of 6.1.0.Beta2 (which will be released soon).

Answer (score 3):

I have solved this issue by edit pom in maven.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
        <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.0.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
                <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: What version drool complier are you using. This did not worked for me.

Comment: Hi not helping your advise.

Comment: Note: I can trigger drools 5.0.1 rules from within Java8, the key thing is compiling them to a package.

I tried this change, does not make any difference. It still gives me the 'class format error'.



RuleBaseTask failed: wrong class format
at org.drools.contrib.DroolsCompilerAntTask.execute(DroolsCompilerAntTask.java:173)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

Answer (score 1):

Update org.eclipse.jdt.core.jar to latest available one .

In our case we have updated org.eclipse.jdt.core-3.5.1.v_972_R35x.jar   to   org.eclipse.jdt.core_3.11.2.v20160128-0629.jar .

This is the jar which decides the java_version with which the drools code will get compiled.

once ur old java-6 compatible drools code getting compiled in java -8 . u can run it using java -8 without any such error . 
These are proven steps .
Please revert back if any doubt .

Comment: If these are proven steps, can you please provide some sources for further reading?

Comment: Only this change is enough or the ecj compiler is also required? 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56095925/strange-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-when-compiling-drools-rules-v5-0-1-on

Answer (score 0):

Update your org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler(ecj.jar) to latest i.e, use ecj-4.4.jar and try.

Comment: Could you please add more details so the user can understand why he has to change that jar file

Answer (score 0):

ECJ, which is used to compile java code in your rules, only began supporting Java 8 syntax recently with Luna (4.4) so an update is required.

If you are wanting to use Java 8 syntax in your rules you will also want to use Drools 6.4.0.Final as they now recognizing Java 8 as Java 8 (they were mapping 8 over to 7 to fix issues with ECJ 4.3)

MVEL 2.2.X version or later, which is a shorthand alternative to Java syntax, also supports Java 8.