# Drools 6.3 error when using java 8

Tags: java, eclipse, drools

I am new to Drools and I am using Drools 6.3 final along with java 1.8 on eclipse. I am not using ant/Maven for building my project. The same project used to work fine with java 1.6 and Drools 5.1.

Now when i try to run the project, I get an error :

```
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.drools.core.base.accumulators.BigDecimalAverageAccumulateFunction cannot be cast to org.drools.runtime.rule.AccumulateFunction
com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSCC0037: A runtime exception was thrown by the MessageListener.onMessage() method. A message consumer with a registered message listener received an exception from the onMessage() method. The onMessage() method should be changed to avoid throwing exceptions.
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.NLSServices.createException(NLSServices.java:313)
at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.nls.NLSServices.createException(NLSServices.java:388)
at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsErrorUtils.createException(JmsErrorUtils.java:104)
at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsMessageConsumerImpl$JmsProviderMessageListener.handleOnMessageThrowable(JmsMessageConsumerImpl.java:1178)
at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsMessageConsumerImpl$JmsProviderMessageListener.onMessage(JmsMessageConsumerImpl.java:1050)
at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQAsyncConsumerShadow.honourNoLocal(WMQAsyncConsumerShadow.java:566)
at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQAsyncConsumerShadow.consumer(WMQAsyncConsumerShadow.java:400)
at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.RemoteAsyncConsume.driveConsumer(RemoteAsyncConsume.java:1527)
at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.RemoteDispatchThread.run(RemoteDispatchThread.java:395)
at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueItem.runTask(WorkQueueItem.java:209)
at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.SimpleWorkQueueItem.runItem(SimpleWorkQueueItem.java:100)
at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueItem.run(WorkQueueItem.java:224)
at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueManager.runWorkQueueItem(WorkQueueManager.java:298)
at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.workqueue.WorkQueueManagerImplementation$ThreadPoolWorker.run(WorkQueueManagerImplementation.java:1220)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.drools.core.base.accumulators.BigDecimalAverageAccumulateFunction cannot be cast to org.drools.runtime.rule.AccumulateFunction
at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsMessageConsumerImpl$JmsProviderMessageListener.handleOnMessageThrowable(JmsMessageConsumerImpl.java:1180)
... 10 more
```

I have also tried the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22493865/1833437).

Also earlier I was getting this error which sometimes occurs or sometimes doesnt :

```
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/drools/builder/CompositeKnowledgeBuilder
com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSCC0037: A runtime exception was thrown by the MessageListener.onMessage() method. A message consumer with a registered message listener received an exception from the onMessage() method. The onMessage() method should be changed to avoid throwing exceptions.
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.NLSServices.createException(NLSServices.java:313)
at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.nls.NLSServices.createException(NLSServices.java:388)
at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsErrorUtils.createException(JmsErrorUtils.java:104)
at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsMessageConsumerImpl$JmsProviderMessageListener.handleOnMessageThrowable(JmsMessageConsumerImpl.java:1178)
at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsMessageConsumerImpl$JmsProviderMessageListener.onMessage(JmsMessageConsumerImpl.java:1050)
at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQAsyncConsumerShadow.honourNoLocal(WMQAsyncConsumerShadow.java:566)
at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQAsyncConsumerShadow.consumer(WMQAsyncConsumerShadow.java:400)
at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.RemoteAsyncConsume.driveConsumer(RemoteAsyncConsume.java:1527)
at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.RemoteDispatchThread.run(RemoteDispatchThread.java:395)
at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueItem.runTask(WorkQueueItem.java:209)
at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.SimpleWorkQueueItem.runItem(SimpleWorkQueueItem.java:100)
at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueItem.run(WorkQueueItem.java:224)
at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.workqueue.WorkQueueManager.runWorkQueueItem(WorkQueueManager.java:298)
at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.workqueue.WorkQueueManagerImplementation$ThreadPoolWorker.run(WorkQueueManagerImplementation.java:1220)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/drools/builder/CompositeKnowledgeBuilder
at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsMessageConsumerImpl$JmsProviderMessageListener.handleOnMessageThrowable(JmsMessageConsumerImpl.java:1180)
... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/drools/builder/CompositeKnowledgeBuilder
```

Can anyone please guide me as to why these errors are occuring and what could be the possible solutions?

PS : the Drools jar which I have included in my build path :

```
drools-compiler-6.3.0.Final.jar
drools-core-6.3.0.Final.jar
kie-api-6.3.0.Final.jar
kie-internal-6.3.0.Final.jar
knowledge-api-6.3.0.Final-sources.jar
org.apache.servicemix.bundles.drools-5.6.0.Final_1.jar -- this is the latest which i could find
```

Comment: Are you compiling your rules from a DRL (or similar) resource? Or are you trying to restore a KBase that was built with 5.1?

Comment: Yes, compiling rules from a DRL and also did not really understand what you mean by 'restore a KBase'?

Comment: In Drools there is a way to serialize a KBase and store it somewhere else so you don't need to recompile the rules it contains every time you start your app.

Either way, the strange thing I see in your first stacktrace is that it doesn't mention any class from your code (unless you are working on IBM's JMS implementation itself) nor from Drools. It would be interesting to see where and how the KieBuilder (or its concrete implementation, CompositeKnowledgeBuilder) is being used in your app.

Another question is: what JDK implementation are you using?

Comment: What @EstebanAliverti didn't say explicitly: class `org.drools.runtime.rule.AccumulateFunction` is from Drools 5.x and should not appear in a Drools application that has been compiled using 6.x and is being executed with matching jars. Also, `NoClassDefFoundError` typically indicates that there is a mixup between compile time and runtime w.r.t. what was reachable on the classpath. Check the installation (Eclipse), check what the IBM stuff implies, check the runtime setup.